# my indexOf keeps finding the character at the same postition how can i solve it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, substring, indexof

```js
for(let j=0; j<=z;j++)
  {
  if( text[i+1].indexOf(y[j]) > -1 )
    {
    con++;
    temp = (text[i+1].indexOf(y[j]));
    text[i+1].substring(temp);
    console.log(text[i+1].indexOf(y[j]))
```

this is code counts whenever a letter of the array `y` is in the string of `text[i+1]` but instead of going through the whole word to find the letter in other position it stays in the first position it finds.

Example:

```js
 text[i+1] = 'debefeene' 
 y = ['e','e','e','e']
```

```
 // My expected output would be:
1
3
5
6
8
 // The actual output is:
1
1
1
1
```

I tried using substring but is not really working.

**z equals the length of the string text[i+1]**

Comment: Please post you complete code. What is 'con' for example? We can't guess code you don't post.

Comment: `String.prototype.indexOf` will start looking the first occurrence from the specified index on the second argument. It defaults to `0`. So if you want the next occurrence you'll have to use the index of the last occurrence as the second argument to it.

Comment: con is only a counter

Comment: @MinusFour thanks, i replace indexOf with lastIndexOf but it keeps repeating  i found this code but im kind of confused can u explain to me please? :D https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf#finding_all_the_occurrences_of_an_element

Comment: I should have said, "previous ocurrence" instead. You don't need to use `lastIndexOf`. Look at the documentation for [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). Look at the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what did you try. That's why I can't tell what is the issue with your code. Look at my solution. It's quite self-explanatory. The 2nd "if" is not necessary. I just added it to stop the loop if there isn't any item left to search for.

```js
let text = "debefeene"
let find = ['e','e','e','e', 'e'];

let positions = [];

for(let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] == find[0]) {
    positions.push(i);
    find.pop();
  }
  if (!find.length) break;
}

console.log(positions);
```